# Monte-Carlo Fitting on python data

Tags: python, debugging, regression, curve-fitting, montecarlo

I have written a Monte-Carlo simulation to fit 49 data points with asymmetric error bars. Since the errors are asymmetric on both axis, I cannot simply use scipy.optimize.curve_fit module. This is my basic approach:

1. Generate a list of 1000 random numbers from within the confidence level (error range) using triangular probability distribution distribution with maximum probability at a certain data point. Now I have a list of dimensions [49*1000].
2. Convert this list from [49*1000] to [1000*49]. I did this so that I have a data set of 1000 samples of 49 points which are within the error range.
3. Use scipy's curve_fit to fit these 1000 samples seperately and find the free parameters in the function y=m*x+c (c is free parameter and I already know the slope m.)
4. Find mean squared error in each of these 1000 samples using sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error module.
5. Find the index with least Mean squared and use the popt value (c parameter) at this index to plot the fit.

**Working Code:** This is my code:

```
trials=int(1e4)
    
#xdata: most probable x value
#ydata: most probable y value
#xerr6low: lower bound on x error
#xerr6up: upper bound on x error
#yerr6low: lower bound on y error
#yerr6up: upper bound on y error

#generating random number using triangular distribution weighted with highest probability at xdata/ydata:
xarray1=[0]*len(obs6xr)
yarray1=[0]*len(obs6xr)
for i in range(0,len(obs6xr)):
    xarray1[i]=np.random.triangular(xdata[i]-xerr6low[i],xdata[i],xdata[i]+xerr6up[i],trials)
    yarray1[i]=np.random.triangular(ydata[i]-yerr6low[i],ydata[i],ydata[i]+yerr6up[i],trials)

xarray=[list(x) for x  in zip(*xarray1)]
yarray=[list(x) for x  in zip(*yarray1)]


def func(x, c):
    #return (np.log10(a)+(b*(x-12))+np.log10(10**(8+c)))
    #return ((x/1e12)**a)*(b)*(10**(8+c))
    m = 1.65
    mx = [element * m for element in x]
    y = [j+c for j in mx]
    return y

#Fit for the parameters a, b, c of the function func:
popt=np.zeros(trials)
pcov=np.zeros(trials)
print(len(xarray),len(yarray),len(popt))
for i in tqdm(range (trials),desc='Optimizing'):
    popt[i], pcov[i] = curve_fit(func, xarray[i], np.array(yarray[i]))

MSE=np.zeros(trials)
for i in tqdm(range (trials),desc='Calculating MSE'):
    MSE[i]=mean_squared_error(np.array(yarray[i]),func(np.array(xarray[i]),popt[i]))

minimum_MSE=np.amin(MSE)
index_MSE=np.where(MSE == np.amin(MSE))
print('minimum MSE = ',minimum_MSE,'at index = ', index_MSE)
print(popt[index_MSE])

def MbhthShimasakupropc(x,c):
    Mbhth = (10**(c))*(x**1.65)
    return Mbhth

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
x=np.logspace(11,14,trials)
plt.loglog(obs6x,MbhthShimasakuprop(obs6x,popt[index_MSE]))
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
m=np.logspace(np.log10(4e10),np.log10(3e14),1000)
plt.errorbar(obs0x, obs0y, xerr=asymmetric_errorx0, yerr=asymmetric_errory0, fmt='o',color='black', markersize='2.5', ecolor='black',capsize=2, elinewidth=1)
plt.errorbar(obs6x, obs6y, xerr=asymmetric_errorx6, yerr=asymmetric_errory6, fmt='o',color='red', markersize='2.5', ecolor='red',capsize=2, elinewidth=1)
plt.loglog(m,MbhthShimasaku(m,0),color='black',linestyle=':',label='Shimasaku-Ferrarese z=0')

plt.xlim(4e10,3e14)
plt.ylim(1e6,1e11)
plt.legend(['Monte-Carlo Fitting','local relation','z=0','z~6'])
plt.show()
```

**Result:**

[image: Result 1]

As we can see, this code works perfectly fine. But if I change function to 2 parameters (a&b),
`func(x,a,b)` and apply the same code with some small tweaks, the code fails miserably.

**Not Working Code:**

```
trials=int(1e3)

#generating random number:
xarray1=[0]*len(obs6xr)
yarray1=[0]*len(obs6xr)
for i in range(0,len(obs6xr)):
    xarray1[i]=np.random.triangular(xdata[i]-xerr6low[i],xdata[i],xdata[i]+xerr6up[i],trials)
    yarray1[i]=np.random.triangular(ydata[i]-yerr6low[i],ydata[i],ydata[i]+yerr6up[i],trials)

xarray=[list(x) for x  in zip(*xarray1)]
yarray=[list(x) for x  in zip(*yarray1)]

def func(x, a, b):
    y=a*x+b
    return y    

#Fit for the parameters a, b, c of the function func:
popt=[0]*(trials)
pcov=[0]*(trials)
print(len(xarray),len(yarray),len(popt))
for i in tqdm(range (trials)):
    popt[i], pcov[i] = curve_fit(func, np.array(xarray[i]), np.array(yarray[i]))

   
MSE=np.zeros(trials)
for i in tqdm(range (trials)):
    MSE[i]=mean_squared_error(np.array(yarray[i]),func(np.array(xarray[i]),np.array(popt[i])[0],np.array(popt[i])[1]))

minimum_MSE=np.amin(MSE)
index_MSE=np.where(MSE == np.amin(MSE))
print('minimum MSE = ',minimum_MSE,'at index = ', index_MSE)


def MbhthShimasakupropmc(x,m,c):
    Mbhth = (10**(c))*(x**m)
    return Mbhth

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
x=np.logspace(11,14,trials)
plt.loglog(obs6x,MbhthShimasakupropmc(obs6x,*popt[[index_MSE][0][0][0]]))
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
m=np.logspace(np.log10(4e10),np.log10(3e14),1000)
plt.errorbar(obs0x, obs0y, xerr=asymmetric_errorx0, yerr=asymmetric_errory0, fmt='o',color='black', markersize='2.5', ecolor='black',capsize=2, elinewidth=1)
plt.errorbar(obs6x, obs6y, xerr=asymmetric_errorx6, yerr=asymmetric_errory6, fmt='o',color='red', markersize='2.5', ecolor='red',capsize=2, elinewidth=1)
plt.loglog(m,MbhthShimasaku(m,0),color='black',linestyle=':',label='Shimasaku-Ferrarese z=0')

plt.legend(['Monte-Carlo Fitting','local relation','z=0','z~6'])
plt.show()
```

**Result:**

[image: Result 2]

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone help me debug the issue.

Comment: You should try to provide a minimal working example (MWE)

Comment: @fonini Thanks! I updated the question. Hopefully its easier to understand now.